# Objective-C++ undefined symbols when linking C++ constructors

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, appkit, objective-c++

I'm experiencing a strange linker error when building a Mac version of a cross-platform project I'm working on. The cross-platform code is developed in C++ and I'm using Apple's AppKit in Objective-C to manage the UI frontend.
As an example, I'm having a C++ class called UILabel, defined as follow:

```
#pragma once
#include "CoreApplication/Views/Elements/UIElement.h"
namespace CoreApplication {
class UILabel : public UIElement {
    UILabel( const UIIdentifier identifier );
    ~UILabel( void );
...
```

The actual code is in UILabel.cpp:

```
#include "CoreApplication/Views/Elements/UILabel.h"
#if( TARGET_OS == MICROSOFT_WINDOWS_OS )
...
#elif( TARGET_OS == APPLE_MAC_OS )
    #include "CoreApplication/Views/UIMacTarget.h"
#endif
namespace CoreApplication {
UILabel::UILabel( const UIIdentifier identifier )
    : UIElement( identifier )
    , _label( NULL )
    , _textAlignment( TextAlignmentType::Void )
    , _textWeight( TextWeightType::Void )
{
    M_LOG_CONSTRUCTOR
    _CreateHostUIElement();
    _ConnectHostUIElement();
    // Default text attributes:
    SetTextAlignment( TextAlignmentType::Left );
    SetTextWeight( TextWeightType::Normal );
}
...
```

When instantiating a new UILabel object in a Objective-C++ file (.mm), I'm having the following message from clang:

> ld: Undefined symbols:
> CoreApplication::UILabel::UILabel(unsigned int), referenced from:
> -[AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in AppDelegate.o

The Objective-C code in the AppDelegate.mm file is:

```
#import "CoreApplication/Views/Elements/UILabel.h"
using namespace CoreApplication;
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    UILabel label( kNullUIIdentifier );
    Pointer hLabel = CreateMacUILabel( label );
    label.SetLabel( CSTR("Hello Macintosh") );
...
```

The interesting part is that I'm also using a "neutral" String class to work with Windows and MacOS defined as below:

```
#include "CoreServices/Streams/MutableData.h"
namespace CoreServices {
class String : public MutableData {
public:
    String( void );
    String( const String & source );
    String( const char * source );
...
```

and the following code in the same AppDelegate method is being linked without issue:

```
using namespace CoreServices;
@implementation AppDelegate
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    String coreServicesInput( "Hello Macintosh" );
...
```

I checked the build phase order in Xcode but everything seems to be OK: what am I doing wrong here?

Needless to say that this code is working fine on Windows with Visual Studio and C++/winRT UWP.

PS: All code is being compiled/linked in the same project: no library here.

Comment: I see a *declaration* of the `UILabel` constructor, but I don't see its *definition*.

Comment: I just added an extract of the .cpp file with the definition of the UILabel constructor.

Comment: `The actual code is in UILabel.cpp` - so is that file being included in the build?

Comment: On the off-chance it’s relevant: if you’re using Xcode then open the inspector on the right and check that UILabel.cpp is ticked for appropriate targets. Unlike most IDEs and build systems, Xcode’s project structure is completely disjoint from on-disk layout, and it’s easy to end up with things on disk that aren’t present in Xcode at all, or which haven’t been added to all relevant targets.

Comment: The linker can't find ```UILabel::UILabel( unsigned int  argument )```. There is no such a constructor in your provided code.

Comment: @Tommy, I already checked and the cpp files are ticked for the target.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, the UIIdentifier is defined as follow: typedef uint32 UIIdentifier; therefore, the constructor exists !

Comment: @PaulSanders, yes, the file is included in the build.

Comment: As far as I see, the constructor is ```UILabel( const UIIdentifier identifier )``` and not ```UILabel( UIIdentifier identifier )```. Please make sure the methods' declarations and definitions are both similar.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, I just did and the problem is still there. Also, the kNullUIIdentifier is defined as extern const UIIdentifier kNullUIIdentifier;

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, however, you're onto something here: I replaced the UIIdentifier type in the constructor both in the h and cpp files with unsigned int and the problem is gone... Does that mean I cannot use my types in constructors ?

Comment: Of course you can. I guess you have some issues somewhere in your ```typedef```s. Please revise all of your type definitions to see where might be a typo or something weird.

Comment: @ImanAbdollahzadeh, you're right ! The issue did not appear on Windows but my definition of uint32 was not aligned with the one from the system: problem solved for good ;)
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for your answers and comments.
The issue originated from a wrong uint32 type definition in the Mac context. Instead of `unsigned int`, it was `unsigned long` in some conditional #if/#endif header section.

I can use `#include <stdint>` to ensure the common fixed width integer types are correctly defined.

However, I'm now using the `pstdint` header from Paul Hsieh that you can find at http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/pstdint.h

I prefer this version as it comes with some interesting macros for correct printf() usage on those types (my code includes many, many log/debug snippets!).

Comment: Insert standard comment here about `cstdint`.